# Modify HTML pages returned by nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy setup for access to a third party application located inside a intranet from the internet.
Let's say this application is on the URL:

`https://internalserver:8080/` (reachable only from the intranet)

and the proxy is on:

`https://proxyserver/` (reachable from any place in the world)

The proxy is managed by nginx and is working ok. When the user accesses `https://proxyserver/` 
they get the content of the app at `https://internalserver:8080/`.

The problem is that the application is writing absolute URLs in the HTML response so, when the user clicks a link to a new page the browser is trying to locate the page with its internal name, e.g. 
 `https://internalserver:8080/somepage`
instead of
 `https://proxyserver/somepage`.

I know this is a program bug, but I'm not able to modify the program.

Can I intercept the response, modify the URLs and send it (modified) to the final client with nginx? Or maybe with another tool?

**EDIT:** I saw [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/480352/modify-data-being-proxied-by-nginx-on-the-fly) before, but my case is more specific, the quoted question ask for a generic modification. In that case the fast-cgi ad hoc program is the best solution, what I want is a more specific solution for (I think) a more common scenario. while a fast-cgi program can work I´m looking for a easiest and maybe stronger and proved into the real world, solution for this scenario.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify data being proxied by nginx on the fly](http://serverfault.com/questions/480352/modify-data-being-proxied-by-nginx-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is an official Nginx Video on YouTube which demonstrates Inline Content Rewriting.

https://youtu.be/7Y7ORypoHhE?t=20m22s

Indeed with sub_filter

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

In your case, you're looking at something like:

```
location / {
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter_types text/html;
sub_filter "https://internalserver:8080" "https://proxyserver";
}
```

Comment: Does it has any performance penalty?

Answer (score 8):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

> The ngx_http_sub_module module is a filter that modifies a response by
>   replacing one specified string by another.
>
> This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the
>   --with-http_sub_module configuration parameter.
>
> Example Configuration
>
> ```
> sub_filter      </head>
>     '</head><script language="javascript" src="$script"></script>';
> ```