# HTTPS + Nginx Reverse Proxy + URL rewrite

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, https, rewrite

I am trying to direct all HTTPS traffic to Nginx server where it will handle all the requests as HTTP requests to all internal servers. So far, I am able to get the template below to work for most of my servers.

```
server {
    listen 443 default ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letencrypt/live/somesite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letencrypt/live/somesite.com/privkey.pem;
    server_name somesite.com;

    location ^~ /Service {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.1.3;
    }
}
```

However, I am restricted to always having to match up https://somesite.com/Service with http://192.168.1.2/Service in order for the above to work.

I can't have https://somesite.com/Service to work with http://192.168.1.2/Hello.

Or that I can't direct this to other port like https://somesite.com/Service with http://192.168.1.2:3000.

For instance, when I changed the above to this:

```
location /Service/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:80/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.3;
}
```

Using the following logging setup:

```
log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name to: $upstream_addr: $request upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;
```

This is the log I got:

```
[22/Jan/2021:09:56:28 +0000] 172.56.38.95 - - - somesite.com to: 192.168.1.2:80: GET /Service/ HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time 0.004 msec 1611309388.445 request_time 0.004
[22/Jan/2021:09:56:28 +0000] 172.56.38.95 - - - somesite.com to: 192.168.1.2:80: GET /Service/js/default.cache.a331c8c3.js HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1611309388.547 request_time 0.002
[22/Jan/2021:09:56:28 +0000] 172.56.38.95 - - - somesite.com to: 192.168.1.2:80: GET /Service/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time 0.012 msec 1611309388.757 request_time 0.012
[22/Jan/2021:09:56:28 +0000] 172.56.38.95 - - - somesite.com to: 192.168.1.3:80: GET /api/v1/oauth.json?_=1611309389573 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time 0.016 msec 1611309388.771 request_time 0.017
```

It can be seen that from the log that the first three fetches are correct. The fourth one is wrong. No further request was made afterward. After tracing a bit more, I realize that 192.168.1.2 already has a Nginx server running and processing PHP pages using FastCGI. I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

So I tried using **rewrite** in combination of what I have above, but I ran into a Page Not Found. I presume that it doesn't seem to work for HTTPS maybe? Thus, it led me to asking the question of how to configure Nginx to reverse proxy with URL rewrite and HTTPS externally.

Comment: To address the first two cases, use: `proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2/Hello;` or `proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:3000/;` - The final paragraph is confusing, what did you do exactly, and what are the corresponding access log entries?

Comment: The first case doesn't work for the application I am using. The application kept redirecting me back to http://192.168.1.2/Application, which translate to https://somesite.com/Application. The second case doesn't work as well similarly to the first case. In regard to the final paragraph, I follow the answer for [Nginx reverse proxy + URL rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite?noredirect=1&lq=1) and got Page Not Found. I didn't get a chance to look at the log for this case because I don't quite understand how rewrite works.

Comment: After more debugging, I found this problem reoccurring. I have another **location /** block right under the block I listed that is being caught while loading the webpage. Thus, part of requests went to the wrong server in that second location block. That explains the wrong behavior. How to fix this so I can keep both location blocks?

Comment: Those logs are from reverse proxy, I presume. Then, last request isn't a fault of reverse proxy (at least isn't its "direct" fault), your client really queired something not under `/Service/` location tree, and the proxy, according to its configuration, correctly proxied it into another place. Probably that's because your proxy did not change **absoltute addresses** inside javascript code, transferred at request 2 (`default.cache.a331c8c3.js`). If that's the case, please, explore this: https://serverfault.com/questions/713148/modify-html-pages-returned-by-nginx-reverse-proxy

Comment: Oh, that is the exact problem. Now, how to solve it? There is no simple option to modify on the server end. And modifying it on the reverse proxy is not an option, because it prevents me to keep the second location block.

Comment: Okay, this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/932628/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-nginx-reverse-proxy) shows all the possible solutions to this problem. And surprisingly, adding another **location ^~ /api** block solves the problem. I will play around a bit more to find the best solution for my particular problem.

Comment: To avoid future reverse proxy issue, I decided to rewrite the HTML URI content. So I added these two lines: **sub_filter "/api/" "/Service/api/"; sub_filter_once on;** to the location block. And it works similarly to adding another location **api** block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [NGINX documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/), the first example is exactly what you are doing and is well explained:

if you confiure a `location` block with a path1 and a `proxy_pass` with a path2, you'll end up with whole "path tree" being relocated from path1 to path2:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name example.net;
    location /some/path/ {
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com/link/;
    }
}
```

if you'll access `https://example.net/some/path/blah` it'll proxy that to `http://www.example.com/link/blah`.

Next caveat is what exactly your origin server returns. It may emit some HTML, some JS, some CSS, and they all can contain HTTP(S) links; some of them are *relative*, but some arent. The very important consideration is a `proxy_pass` directive doesn't instruct Nginx to rewrite any links inside proxied data. If there are non-relative paths, they'll remain as they were and client will interpret them as instruction to go "outside" of proxied prefix.

As we see in you log file, web server returns some Javascript code on request 2:

```
[22/Jan/2021:09:56:28 +0000] 172.56.38.95 - - - somesite.com to: 192.168.1.2:80: GET /Service/js/default.cache.a331c8c3.js HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1611309388.547 request_time 0.002
```

That code likely contains some non-relative paths, i.e. it has a path starting with `/api/`. Client then makes a request according to that path, which is outside of proxied tree (which is only `/Service/` for now), we see it on the line 4:

```
[22/Jan/2021:09:56:28 +0000] 172.56.38.95 - - - somesite.com to: 192.168.1.3:80: GET /api/v1/oauth.json?_=1611309389573 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time 0.016 msec 1611309388.771 request_time 0.017
```

Nginx, according to its configuration, correctly proxies this request elsewhere (it gets catched with `location /` rule).

There are [several ways](https://serverfault.com/questions/932628/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-nginx-reverse-proxy) to get around that. If you have just a few prefixes used with non-relative paths, and nothing else is already using them, you may just proxy them as they are returned:

```
# (inside a "server" block, above "location /" rule)
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com/api/;
    }
```

Other way is to install a filter in the Nginx using a `ngx_http_sub_module`, which *would alter served content*, updating all URIs to the new base.

Please, bear in mind, there can't be a completely bulletproof way to do this. Links may appear not only in text-based HTML, CSS and JS files, but also in proprietary binary files. And we don't know a priori what links they may contain to proxy them preventively. In the recent past an Adobe Flash was an example of such binary format. Nobody knows what gets invented in the future to expose the same problem.

Comment: Sadly, I did that, but it didn't work. I updated the question with logs this time. Maybe you can spot what is the issue?

Comment: Check comment up there, if that's the case, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Finally, I got a simple working solution. See the comment above. Please update the answer. I will mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use proxying and rewriting.  They need to be done in separate places though.  The proxy is going to pass the same path it receives on to the origin server.  If you want to the rewrite to another location, you would do so on your origin server so it knows to rewrite requests for /service to /hello.  Otherwise you will get a 404 because the origin server won't have any idea what to do with the request for /service.

Comment: Based on what you are saying, it would seem that I need to have two Nginx servers running - one server acting as a reverse proxy and the other server on the origin server acting as an URL rewrite server, is that correct? Is there no other way?

Comment: Negative.  I'm saying rewrite on your origin server.  Having a reverse proxy already implies two servers.  Are you proxying to the same server as your origin?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I tried before, but it didn't work. The reason was that the server returned a HTTP page that references to other resources using relative path (e.g. /api/v1/oauth.json?_=1611309389573). That explains why rewrite won't fix the problem. @Nikita Kipriyanovi was on track with the problem I am having.

Comment: This sounds more like a web page code problem than a server config problem.  I can almost guarantee that the page doesn't have ALL relative URLs based on the behavior described.